# React App not compiling my image or video

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, webpack, create-react-app

I am using create-react-app, and im using a Data.js file where i have object with properties which i spread as props in a tag. But when i run npm start, or deploy my image wont show, and it looks like the compiler puts my video and images in a static/media directory. i tried webpack, file-loader en url-loader but no luck.

home.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Sidebar from '../components/SideBar'
import NavBar from '../components/NavBar'
import HeroSection from '../components/HeroSection'
import InfoSection from '../components/InfoSection'
import { homeObjOne, homeObjTwo, homeObjThree } from '../components/InfoSection/Data'


//set sidebar navbar toggle states
//default state toggle is 


const Home = () => {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)

    const toggle = () => {
        setIsOpen(!isOpen)
    }
    return (
        <>
            <Sidebar isOpen={isOpen} toggle={toggle} />
            <NavBar toggle={toggle} />
            <HeroSection />
            <InfoSection {...homeObjOne} />
            <InfoSection {...homeObjTwo} />
            <InfoSection {...homeObjThree} />
        </>
    )
}

export default Home
```

Data.js

```
import reactImage from '../assets/images/react.svg'
import reactImg2 from '../assets/images/draw_and_publish.png'

export const homeObjOne = {
    id: 'about',
    lightBg: false,
    lightText: false,
    lightTextDescription: true,
    topLine: 'Create SVGs for your configurators easily',
    headLine: 'With the Map Tool',
    description: 'Quickly and easily draw available lot using the drawing tool',
    buttonLabel: 'Try it for free >',
    imgStart: false,
    img: require('../assets/images/react.svg'),
    alt: 'Drawing',
    dark: true,
    primary: true,
    darkText: false,
}

export const homeObjTwo = {
    id: 'usage',
    lightBg: true,
    lightText: false,
    lightTextDescription: false,
    topLine: 'Usage is very easy, use these four steps to ',
    headLine: 'create your first project',
    description: 'Get to know the app easily in these 4 simple steps',
    buttonLabel: 'Try it for free >',
    imgStart: true,
    img: {reactImage},
    alt: 'Steps',
    dark: true,
    primary: true,
    darkText: false,

}

export const homeObjThree = {
    id: 'publish',
    lightBg: false,
    lightText: false,
    lightTextDescription: true,
    topLine: 'Publish your drawings',
    headLine: 'as SVG or as an Iframe',
    description: 'and import it into your projects',
    buttonLabel: 'Try it for free >',
    imgStart: false,
    img: {reactImg2},
    alt: 'Publish',
    dark: true,
    primary: true,
    darkText: false,

}
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { InfoContainer, InfoWrapper, InfoRow, Column1, Column2, TextWrapper, TopLine, Heading, Subtitle, BtnWrap, ImgWrap, Img } from './InfoElements'
import { Button } from '../ButtonElement'
// import reactImage from '../assets/images/react.svg'
//n


const InfoSection = ({ lightBg, id, imgStart, topLine, lightText, lightTextDescription, darkText, headLine, description, buttonLabel, img, alt, primary, dark, dark2 }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <InfoContainer lightBg={lightBg} id={id}>
                <InfoWrapper>
                    <InfoRow imgStart={imgStart}>
                        <Column1>
                            <TextWrapper>
                                <TopLine>
                                    {/* Create SVGs for your configurators easily */}
                                    {topLine}
                                </TopLine>
                                <Heading lightText={lightText}>
                                    {/* With the Map Tool */}
                                    {headLine}
                                </Heading>
                                <Subtitle darkText={darkText} lightTextDescription={lightTextDescription}>
                                    {/* Quickly and easily draw available lot using the drawing tool */}
                                    {description}
                                </Subtitle>
                                <BtnWrap>
                                    <Button to='signup'
                                        smooth={true}
                                        duration={500}
                                        spy={true}
                                        exact="true"
                                        offset={-80}
                                        primary={primary ? 1 : 0}
                                        dark={dark ? 1 : 0}
                                        dark2={dark2 ? 1 : 0}>
                                        {/* Try it for free */}
                                        {buttonLabel}
                                    </Button>
                                </BtnWrap>
                            </TextWrapper>
                        </Column1>
                        <Column2>
                            <ImgWrap>
                                <Img src={img} alt={alt} />
                            </ImgWrap>
                        </Column2>
                    </InfoRow>
                </InfoWrapper>
            </InfoContainer>
        </>
    )
}

export default InfoSection
```

InfoElements (styled components)

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
// import { homeObjOne } from './Data'


//$ variables dependant on Data.js property values

export const InfoContainer = styled.div`
color: #fff;
background: ${({ lightBg }) => (lightBg ? '#f9f9f9' : '#d3d3d3')};
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    padding: 100px 0;
}
`

export const InfoWrapper = styled.div`
display: grid;
z-index: 1;
height: 860px;
width: 100%;
max-width: 1100px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
padding: 0 24px;
justify-content: center;
`

export const InfoRow = styled.div`
display: grid;
grid-auto-columns: minmax(auto, 1fr);
align-items: center;
grid-template-areas: ${({ imgStart }) => (imgStart ? `'col2 col1'` : `'col1 col2'`)};

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    grid-template-areas: ${({ imgStart }) => (imgStart ? `'col1' 'col2'` : `'col1 col1' 'col2 col2'`)};
}
`

export const Column1 = styled.div`
margin-bottom: 15px;
padding: 0 15px;
grid-area: col1;
`

export const Column2 = styled.div`
margin-bottom: 15px;
padding: 0 15px;
grid-area: col2;
`

export const TextWrapper = styled.div`
max-width: 540px;
padding-top: 0;
padding-bottom: 60px;
`

export const TopLine = styled.p`
color: #393939;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 16px;
font-weight: 700;
letter-spacing: 1.4px;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin-bottom: 16px;
`

export const Heading = styled.h1`
margin-bottom: 24px;
font-size: 48px;
line-height: 1.1;
font-weight: 600;
color: ${({ lightText }) => (lightText ? '#f7f8fa' : '#000000')};


@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    font-size: 32px;
}

`

export const Subtitle = styled.div`
max-width: 440px;
margin-bottom: 35px;
font-size: 18px;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
line-height: 24px;
color: ${({ darkText }) => (darkText ? '#ffffff' : '#000000')};
`

export const BtnWrap = styled.div`
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-start;
`

export const ImgWrap = styled.div`
max-width: 555px;
height: 100%;
`

export const Img = styled.div`
width: 100%;
margin: 0 0 10px 0;
padding: 0;

/* background-image: url('../images/react.svg'); */
`
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**you img is a img component not a div component so rename its with img not a styled.div **

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).